# Get rows whose timestamps are within specific sliding window time interval pandas (Time Series)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
i = pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(time.time(), time.time()+5000, 10), unit='ms').sort_values()
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10),'B':range(10,30,2),'C':range(10,40,3)},index = i)

df
                         A   B   C
1970-01-19 04:28:30.030  0  10  10
1970-01-19 04:28:30.374  1  12  13
1970-01-19 04:28:31.055  2  14  16
1970-01-19 04:28:32.026  3  16  19
1970-01-19 04:28:32.234  4  18  22
1970-01-19 04:28:32.569  5  20  25
1970-01-19 04:28:32.595  6  22  28
1970-01-19 04:28:33.520  7  24  31
1970-01-19 04:28:33.882  8  26  34
1970-01-19 04:28:34.019  9  28  37
```

What I want is, for each index, the last row which is within '1s' interval from that index:

```
df2
                                    ix            A   B   C
1970-01-19 04:28:30.030  1970-01-19 04:28:30.374  1  12  13
1970-01-19 04:28:30.374  1970-01-19 04:28:31.055  2  14  16
1970-01-19 04:28:31.055  1970-01-19 04:28:32.026  3  16  19
1970-01-19 04:28:32.026  1970-01-19 04:28:32.595  6  22  28
1970-01-19 04:28:32.234  1970-01-19 04:28:32.595  6  22  28
1970-01-19 04:28:32.569  1970-01-19 04:28:33.520  7  24  31
1970-01-19 04:28:32.595  1970-01-19 04:28:33.520  7  24  31
1970-01-19 04:28:33.520  1970-01-19 04:28:34.019  9  28  37
1970-01-19 04:28:33.882  1970-01-19 04:28:34.019  9  28  37
1970-01-19 04:28:34.019             nan          nan nan nan
```

I am currently doing this with loops. At each index I am using `df.between_time` to get all the rows in the time interval and then selecting the last row. But it is really slow, as expected. I need something like `df.shift` for time, I checked out `tshift` and `shift(periods = 1, freq = 'S')` but they do not work like shift, rather they add specified time to each index. Can somebody help me in achieving this? Thanks.

Note:
The `ix` columns in the desired output is optional.

PS: If a `min_periods` parameter (like `pd.df.rolling`) is possible, that would be great!

---

EDIT:

For a starting df:

```
                         A   B   C
1970-01-19 04:28:34.883  0  10  10
1970-01-19 04:28:34.900  1  12  13
1970-01-19 04:28:35.531  2  14  16
1970-01-19 04:28:36.845  3  16  19
1970-01-19 04:28:37.664  4  18  22
1970-01-19 04:28:38.332  5  20  25
1970-01-19 04:28:38.444  6  22  28
1970-01-19 04:28:38.724  7  24  31
1970-01-19 04:28:38.787  8  26  34
1970-01-19 04:28:38.951  9  28  37

df['time'] = df.index
def last_time(time):
    time = str(time)
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time[11:],'%H:%M:%S.%f')
    end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
    return df.between_time(start_time = str(start_time)[11:-7],end_time= 
                                        str(end_time)[11:-7]).iloc[-1]
df.apply(lambda x:last_time(x['time']),axis = 1)

# Output:
                         A   B   C                    time
1970-01-19 04:28:34.883  1  12  13 1970-01-19 04:28:34.900
1970-01-19 04:28:34.900  1  12  13 1970-01-19 04:28:34.900
1970-01-19 04:28:35.531  2  14  16 1970-01-19 04:28:35.531
1970-01-19 04:28:36.845  3  16  19 1970-01-19 04:28:36.845
1970-01-19 04:28:37.664  4  18  22 1970-01-19 04:28:37.664
1970-01-19 04:28:38.332  9  28  37 1970-01-19 04:28:38.951
1970-01-19 04:28:38.444  9  28  37 1970-01-19 04:28:38.951
1970-01-19 04:28:38.724  9  28  37 1970-01-19 04:28:38.951
```

But as you can see, I can only get `second` level accuracy, that is it is considering between `34 to 35`, hence it is missing `35.531` which is within interval from both `34.883` and `34.900`.

Comment: The difficult part about your question is that you want it relative to each row, and thus it's not possible to use `rolling`, since it will keep a `1 second` window rolling down. I cannot think if a `pandas` or `numpy` method for this.

Comment: I will add, what I am currently doing, if that helps

Comment: Added code, please check if you can think of something else?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your time is sorted, then the corresponding row for row 2 would be strictly larger than that for row 1.
eg: if row 6 is the row for row1, then row2 would only need to search row that is >=6

With this in mind we just need to loop through the index once(complexity linear : O(n)):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def time_compare(t1,t2):
     return datetime.strptime(t1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timestamp() - datetime.strptime(t2,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timestamp() < 1

index_j = []
cursor = 0
tmp = list(df.index)
for i in tmp:
    if cursor < len(tmp):
        pass
    else:
        index_j.append(cursor-1)
        continue
    while time_compare(tmp[cursor],i):
        cursor += 1
        if cursor < len(tmp):
            pass
        else:
            break
    index_j.append(cursor-1)
```

Using this df:

```
>>> df
                         A   B   C
1970-01-19 04:28:34.883  0  10  10
1970-01-19 04:28:34.900  1  12  13
1970-01-19 04:28:35.531  2  14  16
1970-01-19 04:28:36.845  3  16  19
1970-01-19 04:28:37.664  4  18  22
1970-01-19 04:28:38.332  5  20  25
1970-01-19 04:28:38.444  6  22  28
1970-01-19 04:28:38.724  7  24  31
1970-01-19 04:28:38.787  8  26  34
1970-01-19 04:28:38.951  9  28  37



>>> index_j
[2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Using the index:

```
>>> [tmp[i] for i in index_j]
['1970-01-19 04:28:35.531', '1970-01-19 04:28:35.531', '1970-01-19 04:28:35.531', '1970-01-19 04:28:37.664', '1970-01-19 04:28:38.444', '1970-01-19 04:28:38.951', '1970-01-19 04:28:38.951', '1970-01-19 04:28:38.951', '1970-01-19 04:28:38.951', '1970-01-19 04:28:38.951']
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got an answer, hence sharing, if anyone has a better answer you are most welcome to add it.

```
i = pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(time.time(), time.time()+5000, 10), unit='ms').sort_values()
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10),'B':range(10,30,2),'C':range(10,40,3)},index = i)
df
df
                         A   B   C
1970-01-19 04:28:30.030  0  10  10
1970-01-19 04:28:30.374  1  12  13
1970-01-19 04:28:31.055  2  14  16
1970-01-19 04:28:32.026  3  16  19
1970-01-19 04:28:32.234  4  18  22
1970-01-19 04:28:32.569  5  20  25
1970-01-19 04:28:32.595  6  22  28
1970-01-19 04:28:33.520  7  24  31
1970-01-19 04:28:33.882  8  26  34
1970-01-19 04:28:34.019  9  28  37

df['time'] = df.index
def last_time(time):
    time = str(time)
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time[11:],'%H:%M:%S.%f')
    end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
    tempdf = df.between_time(*pd.to_datetime([str(start_time),str(end_time)]).time).iloc[-1]
    if str(tempdf['time']) == str(time):
        tempdf.iloc[:] = np.nan
        return tempdf
    else:
        return tempdf
df.apply(lambda x:last_time(x['time']),axis = 1)

                           A     B     C                        time
1970-01-19 04:28:34.883  2.0  14.0  16.0  1970-01-19 04:28:35.531000
1970-01-19 04:28:34.900  2.0  14.0  16.0  1970-01-19 04:28:35.531000
1970-01-19 04:28:35.531  NaN   NaN   NaN                         NaN
1970-01-19 04:28:36.845  4.0  18.0  22.0  1970-01-19 04:28:37.664000
1970-01-19 04:28:37.664  6.0  22.0  28.0  1970-01-19 04:28:38.444000
1970-01-19 04:28:38.332  9.0  28.0  37.0  1970-01-19 04:28:38.951000
1970-01-19 04:28:38.444  9.0  28.0  37.0  1970-01-19 04:28:38.951000
1970-01-19 04:28:38.724  9.0  28.0  37.0  1970-01-19 04:28:38.951000
1970-01-19 04:28:38.787  9.0  28.0  37.0  1970-01-19 04:28:38.951000
1970-01-19 04:28:38.951  NaN   NaN   NaN                         NaN
```